# Converting a heatmap image in the JPEG format to categories in python

Tags: python, numpy, jpeg, heatmap

I have a massive heatmap photo in the JPEG format and I'd like to convert the entries to 5 different categories based on the color of each one, and store the final result in three 2D-numpy arrays (One for section A, one for section B, one for section C).

The categories are as follows:

Red: 5,
Dark brown: 4,
Light brown: 3,
Light orange: 2,
White: 1

You can see the cropped photo that shows only a few top rows in the JPEG format in the following image:

[image: Heatmap]

How can I do this in python?

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a code writing service, please post the code you already have so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you install and use `OpenCV` to help with the processing. This also provides a Python library to work with.

The following works for the heatmap you have given. You will need to modify it accordingly for your massive heatmap.

It first crops the image into 3, one for `A`, `B` and `C` respectively. Next it extracts the pixels for each category colour, converts them first to white and then resizes each to a `16 x 16` greyscale image. Next it converts non zero values to the current category value and adds this to your array.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2    


def parse_image(img):

    # Start with all zeros in a 16x16 array
    data = np.zeros((16, 16), dtype=int)

    # List holding min and max BGR values for each category

    categories = [
        (5, (0, 0, 250), (5, 5, 255)),             # Red
        (4, (5, 60, 152), (12, 78, 160)),          # Dark brown
        (3, (9, 105, 225), (18, 120, 240)),        # Light brown
        (2, (220, 235, 250), (230, 245, 255)),     # Light orange
        (1, (250, 250, 250), (255, 255, 255)),     # White
        ]

    for category, bgr_min, bgr_max in categories:
        # Extract pixels in the required range and convert them to 255
        mask = cv2.inRange(img, bgr_min, bgr_max)
        image_cat = cv2.bitwise_or(img, np.full(img.shape, 255, dtype=np.uint8), mask=mask)

        # Convert the image into greyscale
        image_grey = cv2.cvtColor(image_cat, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Resize the image to 16x16
        values = cv2.resize(image_grey, (16, 16))

        # Convert non black values into the current category value
        values[values > 0] = category

        # Add the values to the data array
        data = data + values

    return data


# Load the heatmap    
image_src = cv2.imread("heatmap.jpg")
cv2.imshow("Source", image_src) 

# Crop into 3 sub images

starty = 28
cropx = 234
cropy = 184
images = []

for number, startx in enumerate([30, 303, 572], start=1):
    images.append(image_src[starty:starty+cropy,startx:startx+cropx])

# Parse A, B and C    
abc = [parse_image(img) for img in images]
print abc
```

So for the heatmap you provided you would get the following output (which could be reshaped into a single array):

```
[array([[2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2],
       [4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2],
       [4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 3, 5],
       [3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3],
       [4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5],
       [3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2],
       [4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2]]), array([[2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
       [3, 3, 4, 3, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3],
       [2, 0, 3, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]), array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5],
       [2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
   [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2]])]
```

Note, working with JPG images means there will be artefacts in image, so colours will not have exact values. This is why there are min and max values. Also normally you will see `RGB` values. But here you will be working with `BGR` values instead. You will need to tweak the min max values to ensure you do not get any `0` values.